# django python optimize filter queries

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have several params:
age, height, weight and so on.

I need to make search by this params.
Right now I can do it like this:

```
persons.vip = Person.get_vip()
params.search.age = request.GET.get('age')
    if params.search.age:
        range = params.search.age
        persons.vip = persons.vip.filter(age__gte=range)
    else:
        do somethin

params.search.weight= request.GET.get('weight')
    if params.search.weight:
        range = params.search.weight
        persons.vip = persons.vip.filter(age__gte=range)
    else:
        do somethin
```

And the same code block for other params like height and so on.

How do I optimize this code and get rid off code repetition?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what your `do somethin` block does.

If we could assume it's empty, you can have a simple map like:

```
param_filters_map = {
    'weight': 'age__gte',
    'height': 'weight__gte', 
    ...}
```

And then iterate over it:

```
for request_param_name, filter_name in param_filters_map.items():
    request_param = request.GET.get(request_param_name):
    if request_param:
        persons.vip = persons.vip.filter(**{filter_name: request_param})
```

If it's not empty than I would try to think if it's possible to apply the logic in those blocks **before** the cycle over parameters (if there's some default behavior which we should overwrite with request params).